# XMLSignature value changes after upgrading java

Tags: java, xml-signature

We have a message flow in Websphere Message Broker v. 7 (running on Java 6) which signs an XML message using a given keystore with a certificate and a private key.

However, after migrating to IIB v. 9 (which runs on Java 7), it started creating a different result for the same XML message. The only difference is the signature value field.

As a result, the receiver party says the message is signed in a wrong way.

Why can it be so?
The keystore is the same in both environments.

Here're the fragments of the code which perform signing:

```
    XMLSignatureFactory sigFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance();
    SignedInfo signedInfo = createSignedInfo(sigFactory, timestamp, timestampId, body, getBodyId(body));
    .........

    XMLSignature sig = sigFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo);
    DOMSignContext sigContext = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, security);
    .........

    sig.sign(sigContext);
```

We have tried comparing java.security in both environments but it seems to be the same.

We use RSA-SHA1:

```
 private SignedInfo createSignedInfo(XMLSignatureFactory sigFactory, Element timestamp, String timesetampId, Element body, String bodyId) throws Exception {
    ExcC14NParameterSpec spec = new ExcC14NParameterSpec(Arrays.asList(SOAP_SCHEMA.getPrefix()));
    CanonicalizationMethod canonicalizationMethod = sigFactory.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE, spec);
    List<Reference> references = createSignatureReferences(sigFactory, timestamp, timesetampId, body, bodyId);
    return sigFactory.newSignedInfo(canonicalizationMethod, sigFactory.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null), references);
}
```

Comment: What SignatureMethod are you setting for the SignedInfo in the createSignedInfo method? Can you include the source of that method too?

Comment: We use RSA-SHA1. I've updated the original post, including the source of the createSignedInfo method

Comment: I've found this, sounds like your case but I cannot find info on the exact Java version for MB 7 and IIB 9: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21697128

Comment: Thank you very much! It's not my issue but at least I know that ibmxmlcrypto.jar may be the culprit. I temporarily replaced the jar with the jar from Java 6, and it works now.

I think we will write to IBM on this issue.